# Symfony How to implement Models

Tags: symfony1

I am using Symfony 1.4 and already created schema.yml, 3 of them, and created the database.yml with multiple connection.

And executed the build --model of symfony and created classes one of them is "Schedule" which came from the schema having columns: id, name, description....

How do use that class to use its method or function, the setter and getters? Books says that there are setters and getter if a model was generated.

How do I retrieve data with filters?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague. But from your model you can do:

**Create an entry:**

```
$schedule = new Schedule();
$schedule->setName('foo');
$schedule->setDescription('bar');
$schedule->save();
```

**Find all entries**

```
$schedules = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Schedule')->findAll();
```

**Retrieve one item** (if we assume that one `Schedule` exists with id 1)

```
$schedule = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Schedule')->find(1);
$schedule = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Schedule')->findOneByName('foo');
```

**Access field inside your model**

```
$name        = $schedule->getName();
$description = $schedule->getDescription();
```

---

**Edit:**

**Custom getter**, in `ScheduleTable.class.php`:

```
public function findByStatusAndRangeTime($status, $start, $end)
{
  $q = $this->createQuery('s');
  $q->where('s.status = ? AND s.time_start < ? AND s.time_end > ?', array($status, $start, $end));

  return $q->execute();
}
```

Then, you can call it using:

```
$schedule = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Schedule')->findByStatusAndRangeTime('pending', '1:00', '5:00');
```

Comment: this line  "Doctrine_Core::getTable('Schedule')->find(1)" how does the system know "1" is to "id" or not any columns? how can I specify the filters?

Comment: Because `id` is the default primary key in Doctrine. So `find()` method use the PK to search on the table. What do you mean by filters?

Comment: Like if for example Schedule has a column of status, time-start and time-end, I would want to filter it to only completed status in a certain time-star up to a certain time end. Like only status = pending, time-start < 1:00 and time-end > 5:00..